# Unable to load class from installed jar in maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I installed by jar file inside of my maven local repository (~/.m2/repository/) by following the tutorial of the 3rd party JARs installation with the groupID, artifactId, version and packaging like this:

mvn install:install-file -Dfile=CAENRFIDLibrary.jar -DgroupId=com.caen -DartifactId=RFIDLibrary -Dversion=4.7.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar.

After updating maven project dependency inside eclipse, the error that appears in my pom.xml disappears. But in my program, I'm not able to load class from jar file. (NB: The package is imported  in the program)

Did someone know how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Check your dependency again.

Comment: Try right click on project --> Maven --> Update Project...

Answer (score 1):

**Update dependency like below in pom file.**

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.caen</groupId>
     <artifactId>CAENRFIDLibrary</artifactId>
     <version>4.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I did project --> Maven --> Update Project and I fill the POM file like above but it still continue to block when I try to load CAENRFIDReader (com.caen.RFIDLibrary.CAENRFIDReader) class from package com.caen.RFIDLibrary.

Comment: Please try to rebuild project again.

Comment: replace your <artifactId>CAENRFIDLibrary</artifactId> with <artifactId>RFIDLibrary</artifactId> in pom dependency

Answer (score 0):

I did by using the right way but it persists always. I am asking myself if the problem is not coming from the jar because it is generate with Ant 1.9.4? May be it is coming from the groupId as the package where all the classes are located is "com.caen.RFIDLibrary"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved, the problem is due to the rxtxcomm jar's file. By trying to load both, CAENRFIDLibrary.jar and rxtxcomm.jar, step-by-step as external lib of the project I found the solution.

Thanks your helps.